# Conditionally enable non-template function c++

Tags: c++, c++11, mpi, portability

#### Background

I'm working on a C++ project in High Performance Computing using MPI. I have a function with a few different overloads, that I use to convert different types into strings:

```
void append(std::string& s, int value);
void append(std::string& s, void* value);
void append(std::string& s, MPI_Request request);
```

This worked fine while I was using Open MPI. In OpenMPI, `MPI_Request` is an alias for `ompi_request_t*`, so each overload has a different signature.

Recently, however, I tried compiling the code with MPICH. In MPICH, `MPI_Request` is an alias for `int`, and the result is that the above code fails to compile because `append` is defined for `int` twice:

```
/home/me/NimbleSM/src/mpi-buckets/src/mpi_err.hpp: At global scope:
/home/me/NimbleSM/src/mpi-buckets/src/mpi_err.hpp:28:6: error: redefinition of ‘void append(std::__cxx11::string&, int)’
 void append(std::string& s, int i) { s.append(std::to_string(i)); }
      ^~~
/home/me/NimbleSM/src/mpi-buckets/src/mpi_err.hpp:17:6: note: ‘void append(std::__cxx11::string&, MPI_Request)’ previously defined here
 void append(std::string& s, MPI_Request request)
```

#### Question

How should I write `append(std::string&, MPI_Request)` so that the compiler ignores it when `MPI_Request` is defined as an `int`, but recognizes it when `MPI_Request` is a library type?

#### Attempted solution: `enable_if` fails

I attempted to write a solution based on `std::enable_if`, where the function is only enabled if `MPI_Request` is a different type than `int`.

```
auto append(std::string& s, MPI_Request request)
    -> typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<MPI_Request, int>::value, void>::type
{ 
    str(s, (void*)request); 
}
```

This fails because when `MPI_Request` is the same as `int`, the statement is always false, and since it's not dependent on any template parameters, the compiler flat-out refuses to compile it.

**How do I fix this, and make `append` contingent on `MPI_Request` being different from `int`?**

Comment: Will you want the same behavior as the `int` overload if `MPI_Request` is an `int`?

Comment: There is no way to emulate SFINAE with non-templates. The main usage point of SFINAE is to avoid instantiating the functions with types which can't be used in functions bodies. Non-templates will not allow you this.

Comment: I want the compiler to ignore the function if MPI_Request is an int. So it just pretends the MPI_Request overload isn't there

Comment: maybe there is a design problem to fix at a higher level as what ever you do, you will never be able to distinguish `void append(std::string& s, int value)` from `void append(std::string& s,int mpi_request)`  (same signature)

Comment: I don't need to distinguish between them; I just need there to be an overload if MPI_Request *isn't* an int. If it is an int, I'm fine with the `int` version being called (I just need the non-int version to not exist)

Comment: @chris: IMO, your answer is fine (and it is my favorite if we cannot use preprocessor macro).

Answer (score 2):

That's unfortunate. The bottom line is that `enable_if` can only be used inside SFINAE context which requires the T - template. To iterate on your idea we can specify our requirements in the return type so that the template matches only `MPI_Request` and only if the `MPI_Request` type is not an `int`.

```
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
using MPI_Request = int;// Or something else

template<typename T>
using T_is_MPI_and_not_also_int = std::conjunction<std::is_same<T,MPI_Request>, std::negation<std::is_same<MPI_Request,int>>>;

template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<T_is_MPI_and_not_also_int<T>::value,void> 
append(std::string& s, T request);
```

[Full example](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstring%3E%0A%23include+%3Ctype_traits%3E%0Ausing+MPI_Request+%3D+float%3B%0A%0Atemplate%3Ctypename+T%3E%0Ausing+T_is_MPI_and_not_int+%3D+std::conjunction%3Cstd::is_same%3CT,MPI_Request%3E,+std::negation%3Cstd::is_same%3CMPI_Request,int%3E%3E%3E%3B%0A%0Atemplate%3Ctypename+T%3E%0Astd::enable_if_t%3CT_is_MPI_and_not_int%3CT%3E::value,void%3E+%0Aappend(std::string%26+s,+T+request)%0A%7B%0A++++std::cout%3C%3C%22I!'m+a+MPI_Request+but+I!'m+ignored+if+I!'m+also+an+int.%22%3B%0A%7D%0Avoid+append(std::string%26+s,+int+request)%0A%7B%0A++++std::cout%3C%3C%22I!'m+an+int.%22%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++std::string+foo%3B%0A++++MPI_Request+req%3B%0A++++append(foo,+req)%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:icc19,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B17+-O2',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+icc+19.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',m:50,n:'0',o:'',t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+icc+19.0.0',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4), you can even see which `cout` line gets inlined into main.

Answer (score 2):

You can make it a function template with defaulted template parameter, which allows SFINAE to work:

```
void append(std::string& s, int value);
void append(std::string& s, void* value);

template <typename MPI_Request_ = MPI_Request,
    typename std::enable_if<
        !std::is_same<MPI_Request_, int>::value
        && std::is_same<MPI_Request_, MPI_Request>::value
    , int>::type = 0>
void append(std::string& s, MPI_Request_ request)
{ 
    str(s, (void*)request);
    // Or, if you want the implementation in the source file,
    // call another function like: append_mpi_request(s, request);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/UNE1Zq)

Comment: Your answer is cleaner than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a low tech solution. Use a preprocessor macro.

```
void append(std::string& s, int value);
void append(std::string& s, void* value);

#ifdef MPI_REQUEST_IS_INT
// No need to declare append() for MPI_Request
#else
void append(std::string& s, MPI_Request request); 
#endif
```

Use the same strategy in the .cpp file.